# Need help understanding this example code

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am semi-new to C# and XAML.

I've watched quite a bit of videos on XAML and how to use the cross-platform template, however I am having quite a hard time understanding navigating from a page to another page, whether it's tabbed to content or master-detail to tabbed. I can't find many examples.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LocalMaster.Views"
            x:Class="LocalMaster.Views.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>


    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <views:ItemsPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

    <!--
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    -->
</MasterDetailPage>
```

What is commented out between  is the original code that Xamarin created. I am a bit confused as to why my version of the code (right above the original) doesn't work. I don't quite fully understand the ":Arguments" and "views:" coding, not sure if this is where my problem lies, of it's just all out wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and any examples of navigating between pages would be awesome too. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a page navigation official document 
 can refer to.(https://xamarin.azureedge.net/developer/xamarin-forms-book/XamarinFormsBook-Ch24-Apr2016.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure I give this a good read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the same as doing the following in C#

```
MyMasterPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(ItemsPage);
```

so that the Detail pane of your MasterDetail contains ItemsPage wrapped in a NavigationPage.  This will allow you to use hierarchical navigation in your Detail pane.

In your code you do not have a NavigationPage, so you won't be able to use the built in Navigation features.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That makes perfect sense. Thanks.